# DateTime adjustment in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows, there is a column which is datetime:

I would like to adjust the time, a little like  00 ± 15 -> 00, and 30±15 ->30.
More precise saying is the minute within the range **46<->15** will change to **00**,  **16<->45** will change to **30**, but it also needs care **± 1 on the hour**

```
datetime
2022/11/15 00:29
2022/11/15 00:29
2022/11/15 00:29
2022/11/15 00:59
2022/11/15 00:59
2022/11/15 00:59
2022/11/15 01:35
2022/11/15 01:35
2022/11/15 01:35
2022/11/15 02:01
2022/11/15 02:01
2022/11/15 02:01
2022/11/15 02:45
2022/11/15 02:45
2022/11/15 02:45
2022/11/15 02:48
2022/11/15 02:48
2022/11/15 02:48
```

After adjustment, it would become

```
datetime
2022/11/15 00:30
2022/11/15 00:30
2022/11/15 00:30
2022/11/15 01:00
2022/11/15 01:00
2022/11/15 01:00
2022/11/15 01:30
2022/11/15 01:30
2022/11/15 01:30
2022/11/15 02:00
2022/11/15 02:00
2022/11/15 02:00
2022/11/15 02:30
2022/11/15 02:30
2022/11/15 02:30
2022/11/15 03:00
2022/11/15 03:00
2022/11/15 03:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.ceil`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html) by 15 minutes and then [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by 30:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.ceil('15Min').dt.floor('30Min')
print (df)
              datetime
0  2022-11-15 00:30:00
1  2022-11-15 00:30:00
2  2022-11-15 00:30:00
3  2022-11-15 01:00:00
4  2022-11-15 01:00:00
5  2022-11-15 01:00:00
6  2022-11-15 01:30:00
7  2022-11-15 01:30:00
8  2022-11-15 01:30:00
9  2022-11-15 02:00:00
10 2022-11-15 02:00:00
11 2022-11-15 02:00:00
12 2022-11-15 02:30:00
13 2022-11-15 02:30:00
14 2022-11-15 02:30:00
15 2022-11-15 03:00:00
16 2022-11-15 03:00:00
17 2022-11-15 03:00:00
```